# Related to IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula, importrange

Say I have two spreadsheets: `name` and `grade`. I have a lot of data in `name` that I want to pull some of into `grade`. I used the following:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("KEY_OF_name","Sheet1!E1")
```

Great! That would pull the data in cell E1 in `name` to `grade` but I want to make the formula more dynamic. With the same function I want to take the number "1" in "E1" from  a cell in `grade`. So if the value of B2 in `grade` is "1", the formula for pulling data to `grade` is:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("KEY_OF_name","Sheet 1!E1")
```

and if the value of B2 in grade is "6", the formula is:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("KEY_OF_name","Sheet 1!E6")
```

I want to write down the range in the function as En where:

- E is the column in name
- n is a number in cell B2 in grade.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
=IMPORTRANGE("KEY_OF_name","Sheet 1!E"&B2)
```